# Taglibs are not recognized when war deployed to jetty 8

Tags: java, maven, jetty, jstl, taglib

I am asking after almost one day struggling with this simple problem.
I have a personal web application which I've been developing on tomcat on my localhost (no problem) since I want to save memory on the server I've decided to deploy it on jetty in production use. And in this moment the problem came. I can not figure out the right configuration of things. My files are as follow:

relevant part of pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
        WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and when render my jsp I obtain this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

instead of recognize it as a taglib.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is your taglibs jars getting copied in lib folder after packaging?

Comment: @VinayLodha yes, the jars are all there

Answer (score 0):

I think JSTL may require this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
             <version>1.2</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I have included it and and problem still persists.

Comment: Unfortunately not even this has helped. What drives me crazy is the fact that everything is OK on tomcat and not on the jetty which should provide the very same handling of taglibs as tomcat.